# Why is Steam showing an Xbox 360 controller that doesn't exist?

Tags: steam, input-method

My (native Linux) Steam client is showing an Xbox 360 controller, though I don't have one, and none have been in my home (and it's a desktop, so seeing it outside can be ruled out).
I tried listing USB devices, detaching devices, looking in the paired Bluetooth devices, and it persists.
What I found in a Google search is a case of stale device drivers in Windows (after it had the controller attached, do it's not the case here).
What can cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in Dolphin emulator, in the controller settings, I had a list of devices, so I looked in it and saw input-remapper gamepad, I installed input-remapper a few months ago to change some mouse settings, but I never used it, turns out it installs a virtual controller and there's nowhere (that I could see) to disable it, since I wasn't using it, I removed input-remapper, and the Xbox 360 controller was gone.